# Why I can't able to hash a password using Mongoose Virtual Setter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to 'setter' virtual method to hash my password. However, the password is not hashing. In fact, it is showing undefined every time I try to access the virtual field. If I try to store the data without the hash password then It stores the data. Some days ago, I tried the same code and it worked. But I don't know why It's not working now.

**Here is My Code Link:** https://github.com/RiyaadHossain/FlipkartClone-Server

**Here is the controller code:**

```
// Sign Up Controller_____________________________________
exports.signup = async (req, res) => {

  // Check If the email already exists or not
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).exec((err, user) => {
    if (user) {
      res.status(400).json({ message: "Email Already Taken..!" });
    }
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: "An Internal Error Occured..!" });
    }
  });

  const { firstName, lastName, email, userName, password } = req.body;

  console.log(password); // Getting Undefined - Here is the problem

  // Create New User
  const newUser = new User({ firstName, lastName, email,  userName, password }); // Error is with the password
  newUser.save((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
    if (data) {
      res.status(500).json({ data });
    }
  });
};
```

**Here is the virtual setter code:**

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      min: 3,
      max: 20,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      min: 3,
      max: 20,
    },
    userName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: [true, "User Name already Taken"],
      index: true,
      trim: true,
      min: 3,
      max: 20,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
    },
    hash_password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["user", "admin"],
      default: "user",
    },
    contactInfo: String,
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

// Hash Password using Bcrypt
userSchema.virtual("password").set(function (password) {
  this.hash_password = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
});

// Instance Method - To compare password
userSchema.methods = {
  authenticate: function (password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.hash_password);
  },
};

module.exports = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

**Previous code Link Where I was able to do that:**

Controller Code: https://github.com/RiyaadHossain/FlipkartClone-Practice-Server/blob/main/src/controller/auth.js

Model Code: https://github.com/RiyaadHossain/FlipkartClone-Practice-Server/blob/main/src/models/user.js

Comment: try `this.set({ hash_password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10) })`, example shown in mongoose [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html#virtual-setters)

Comment: Alright, it's showing the same error. `Error: data and salt arguments required.` And then the app gets crashed. I just copied and pasted your code. ```userSchema.virtual("password").set(function (password) {
  this.set({ hash_password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10) })
});```

Comment: the error seem to be thrown from bcrypt not mongoose, I suspecting that `password` is undefined, try log it out in setter. Another thing I am suspecting is `new User({ firstName, lastName, email,  userName, password })`, if I am not wrong, the default constructor does not take any argument, you can try to convert it to `newUser.password= password` pattern

Comment: Yeah, I also think the error is coming from bcrypt. Ok, let me try something else.

Answer (score 0):

try change  `const newUser = new User({ firstName, lastName, email,  userName, password })` to

```
const newUser = new User()
newUser.firstName = firstName
newUser.lastName = lastName
newUser.email = email
newUser.userName = userName
newUser.password = password
```

Comment: Mongoose will call the virtual setter just fine if you pass properties directly to the constructor.

Comment: Okay, I got the answer. It was a really silly mistake. Actually, as I created a virtual setter method so I have to put the value using the same key whenever I am sending a request from Postman. But, in postman, I was sending the request using the 'hash_password' in JSON format. Then I changed to 'password' to check whether it work or not. Actually, that is the problem. I should use the 'password' key as JSON data as I set the virtual setter method 'password'.  Thanks @wedev_jj for being so helpful. but the new User constructor takes parameter. ***LINK:*** https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html